# CoreData predicate ANY + AND with to-many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have those entities defined in my model:

```
[Sample]
- results (to many relation with [Result])

[Parameter]
- results (to many relation with [Result])
- compliant (number value)

[Result]
- parameter (relation with [Parameter])
- sample (relation with [Sample])
```

For a [Sample] object "MySample", I need to get all [Parameter] objects that have:

```
[Result].compliant = 1 AND [Result].sample = MySample
```

So, I'm trying to fetch [Parameter] objects using predicate that will be a sum of those predicates:

```
// returns all parameters that have a result compliant value equal to 1:
ANY results.compliant = 1

// returns all parameters related with my [Sample] object:
ANY results.sample = MySample
```

Both predicates working as expected, but I would like to use it together, because I need to get all parameters connected with my [Sample] object that have result compliant value equal to 1.

I have tried something like that:

```
ANY (results.compliant = 1 AND results.sample = MySample)
```

but it gives me "invalid predicate" exceptions.

I have also tried to use SUBQUERY, but it gives me those exception:

```
Can't have a non-relationship collection element in a subquery
```

I would like to notice, that query:

```
ANY results.compliant = 1 AND ANY results.sample = MySample
```

is a valid query, but not what I'm looking for.

How to solve this problem with a single predicate that gives me all [Parameter] objects that have a [Result] object connected with my [Sample] object and having compliant value equal to 1 ?

**UPDATE:**

Using NSCompoundPredicate not giving me expected results. I need something like this:

```
ANY (results.compliant = 1 AND results.sample = MySample)
```

and using compound predicate works like that:

```
(ANY results.compliant = 1) AND (ANY results.sample = MySample)
```

Compound predicate gives me parameters that have a result with compliant value equal to 1 and parameters that have a result connected with MySample, but what I need is to get parameters that have result that are connected with MySample AND have compliant value equal to 1 (both conditions have to be complied for a single [Result] object). Any ideas how to achieve that?

**UPDATE 2:**

It appears that I was using wrong SUBQUERY, the solution is to using like it should be used :-) With SUBQUERY I can get the proper result.

Comment: Why not use a compound predicate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm typing this on the phone so there might be syntax errors, but this is where you need a subquery:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(results, $r, $r.compliant = 1 AND $r.sample = %@).@count > 0", mySample]
```

Comment: You forgot @ in count, and wrote @% instead of %@, so this should be: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(results, $r, $r.compliant = 1 AND $r.sample = %@).@count > 0", mySample]` but that's what I was looking for! Previously I have used SUBQUERY in the wrong way, so it throws exceptions, but you solution is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a NSCompoundPredicate.

Create your predicates and add them to an array then assign them as a NSCompoundPredicate like so.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I'm looking for. I'll edit question to explain the problem better.