# Core Data: Multiple conditions inside relational aggregate operations

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an SQLite table used by Core Data with the following elements:

Name: John
LastName: Foobar
Age: 23

Name: Bob
LastName: Baz
Age: 37

Name: Peter
LastName: Fooqux
Age: 32

Name: John
LastName: Bar
Age: 29

Those are all in a to-many relationship from another object "Company". I need to query the database and retrieve all Company objects with employees called "John" but whose last name does NOT contain "Foo".

I did go as far as to make the following predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY employee.name = 'John'"];
```

How do I get to filter only by companies whose Johns don't have "Foo" in their last names?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026765/coredata-predicate-any-and-with-to-many-relationship). [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051948/core-data-subquery-predicate/18052128#18052128) might also help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you named your to-many relationship 'employees', here is a sample that would fetch all companies that fall under your requested criteria.

```
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    //Fetch all companies 
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@“Company” inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(employees, $x, $x.name = ‘John’ AND NOT $x.lastName = ‘Foo’).@count > 0)"];

    //Set the predicate
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;

    NSArray *filteredCompanies = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```